# mcDropDown plugin: how to show parent node attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm using the [mcDropDown](http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm) plugin which is very effective.

Without reporting all the code, I just put the jsfiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/SwxP3/

What I want to do, and I wasted hours of trials, is to get the parent of the selected node.

Example

```
<li rel="1"> 
        Arts &amp; Humanities 
        <ul> 
            <li rel="2"> 
                Photography 
                <ul> 
                    <li rel="3"> 
                        3D 
                    </li> 
                    <li rel="4"> 
                        Digital 
                    </li> 
                </ul> 
            </li> 
            <li rel="5"> 
                History 
            </li> 
            <li rel="6"> 
                            Literature 
            </li> 
        </ul> 
    </li>
```

In such example, if I select "3D" I want to be able to retrieve the rel property of its parent.

I played a bit with the `getValue` function of mcDropDown plugin, without any success.

I saw that this plugin, in the dom tree, creates hidden elements reporting the list tree structure, and also the `getValue` functions uses them, but I couldn't find a way of retrieving the parent (I tried with the `parent()` function of jquery of course)...

Does anybody have an idea of how to get the parent?

I really need this feature, so if somebody has some sulution which includes NOT using mcDropDown but any other plugin (or creating a dropdown natively with css and jquery) it is wellcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#current_rev").html("v"+$.mcDropdown.version);
    $("#category").mcDropdown("#categorymenu",{
        select: function(value,name){
             alert($("[rel="+value+"]").parents('li').attr("rel"))
        }            
    });
});
```

This get's the rel of the parent. Undefined if the selected element doesn't have a parent.

Comment: Many thanx, it was exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: where did you find the documentation for the `select` event? I couldn't find it on the official site http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm

Comment: another question: select callback seems to be fired also when the menu is initialized. Why?

Comment: Under options: select: null                 // callback that occurs when a value is selected